# POSTGRES DATA_TRUNC should return 0 for intervals that has no data

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I am trying to do a time series-like reporting, for that, I am using the Postgres DATA_TRUNC function, it works fine and I am getting the expected output, but when a specific **interval has no record** then it is getting skipped to show, but my expected output is to get the interval also with 0 as the count, below is the query that I have right now. What change I should do to get the intervals that have no data? Thanks in advance.

```
SELECT date_trunc('days', sent_at), count('*')  
FROM (select * from invoice 
WHERE supplier = 'ABC' and sent_at BETWEEN '2021-12-01' AND '2022-07-31') as inv 
GROUP BY date_trunc('days', sent_at)
ORDER BY date_trunc('days', sent_at);
```

Expected: As you can see below, the current output now shows 02/12 and then 07/12, it has skipped dates in the middle, but for me, it should also show 03/12, 04/12, 05/12 with count as 0

Current output
[image]

Comment: Can you share your input tables and expected output?

Comment: please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't seem like you have those dates in your data, in which case you need to [generate](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-srf.html#FUNCTIONS-SRF-SERIES) them. Also, casting your timestamp to date instead of `date_trunc()` can get rid of those zeroes.

```sql
SELECT dates::date, count(*)  filter (where sent_at is not null)
FROM (
  select * 
  from invoice a 
    right join generate_series( '2021-12-01'::date, 
                                '2021-12-31'::date, 
                                '1 day'::interval ) as b(dates)
      on sent_at::date=b.dates) as inv 
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1;
```

Here's a [working example](https://dbfiddle.uk/zLAE11As). Also, please try to improve your question according to [@nbk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5193536/nbk)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74127864/postgres-data-trunc-should-return-0-for-intervals-that-has-no-data#comment130879101_74127864).